# How to send data from android phone using bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have made an application, which shows the latitude and longitude of the device in textview. What I want to do is send that information over bluetooth, which would be received by another device and displayed. How do I go about adding this functionality to my bluetooth application?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you have tried, yet this is always the best place to look at: [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html)

The Android developer site gives you a nice description of everything and of coures, working examples.

Hope that helps.